# Android app crashing trying to use ?attr/variable

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to use an ?attr/var to set color and it keeps crashing saying the list-view xml has an error. If I use a normal color attribute it works fine.

```
2021-02-04 18:10:45.621 13812-13812/com.daford.sermonviewer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.viewer, PID: 13812
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3 in com.viewer:layout/list_item: Binary XML file line #3 in com.viewer:layout/list_item: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3 in com.viewer:layout/list_item: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
```

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="textColor" format="color"/>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LightTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

list-item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="?attr/textColor"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ...
```

Comment: What you are trying to do? If you are trying to create a custom attribute, you are doing it in the wrong way. Read more at https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view

Comment: @PankajKumar I'm trying to find out what is wrong with my code as it is. I followed a tutorial specifically for creating a dark and light theme. https://blog.prototypr.io/implementing-dark-theme-in-android-dfe63e62145d

Comment: ```app:textColor="?attr/textColor"/>```

Comment: Not sure but, textColor would be an issue. Change it to something else like custom TextColor

Comment: @PankajKumar, I changed the variable to txtColor and still same problem

Comment: @Darkman where does that line go? app isn't valid in the TextView

Comment: @JohnSmith `list-item.xml`, at the bottom of your `TextView`. Replace ```android:textColor="?attr/textColor"/>``` with ```app:textColor="?attr/textColor"/>```. And don't forget to put this ```xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.daford.sermonviewer"``` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Use attr/textColor inside style

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name=”android:textColor”>?attr/textColor</item>
</style>
```

then apply this style to textview.

For more details refer [Material Design](https://material.io/blog/android-material-theme-type)

Comment: Where is the color set?